# jQuery color animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, colors

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

This plugin is buggy. I heard there is a new version, where is it?

Want to animate color from #000 to #ccc without jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/).

Comment: Just curious, why not just download the effects portion of jQueryUI? You don't have to take on the entire thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this one: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color ?

It seems it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/LekisS/67Pzu/

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I have just tested this fiddle with Aurora 10a2 and it didn't work